# Build a TextBoxMenu on an AppBarButton

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

How do I create a Menu containing a TextBox like shown in the image below?
[image: screenshot of the win8 startmenu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build apps with HTML and Javascript, this item is called a flyout menu. See this link to a [Quickstart: adding a Flyout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465354).

If you are building apps with C#/VB than there is no Flyout control available. The suggested approach is to use a Popup control, see this question on the MSDN forums where some people from Microsoft are responding to this question: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/6793c93c-072d-4567-b490-812bc5e75c89/

Answer (score 0):

I found the example [How to add a menu to an app bar (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150602.aspx) useful. It uses a Popup with IsLightDismissEnabled = true to create a menu above the AppBar.